# Appium Differenec between port and bootstrap port

Tags: appium

In appium, can anyone please explain me what is the difference between appium port and bootstrap port.

appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723 -bp 4786

Answer (score 1):

Appium port is basically the server port on which appium server is listening. 
Just like we start our http server or node server on some port.

While Bootstrap port is the port to be used on device for appium to talk to the device.
Note : Bootstrap port is only for Android.